# Why doesn't e.Location exist inside EventArgs for LocationChanged?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When we handle the `Control.MouseMove` event, we can get the `Control`'s current `Location` with `e.Location`. Why can't `get` the current `Location` with `Control.LocationChanged`? I know we can get the `Control`'s current `Location` with `Point loc = control.Location;` but that's not the point. This seems a bit inconsistent. Or is there a reason we can't get the current `Location` of the `Control` or `Form` this way?

Comment: Probalby because there is no need...As you said there is already a way to get the location

Answer (score 1):

[`MouseEventArgs.Location`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.location%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) refers to the location of the mouse cursor, not the location of the control.

To get the location of the control, you have to refer to `control.Location` in both the `MouseMove` and the `LocationChanged` events.